# Why is SQL query returning 0? What will be the actual query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
require 'connect_db.php';
require 'User.php';
$stmnt = $con->prepare("select f_name, l_name from user where f_name LIKE :q OR l_name LIKE :q OR dept LIKE :q OR batch LIKE :q OR email LIKE :q");
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q1 = "'%".$q."%'";
$stmnt->bindParam(':q',$q1);
$stmnt->execute();
$results = $stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo count($results);
```

When I am writing it mysql command line it is returning 1 row but this code is not.. please help me to correct it.

My sql query is :`select f_name, l_name from user where f_name LIKE '%s%' or l_name LIKE '%s';`

this is returning 1 row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use parameters they will be sent as is and escaped when needed. You write

```
$q1 = "'%".$q."%'";
```

This means that the string in the end will be `'%something%'` and this will be escaped into the SQL query. You most likely don't want to find strings beginning and ending with `'` so remove them to get `%something%`.

```
$q1 = "%".$q."%";
```

Comment: Good catch. Even better would be getting rid of this `$q2` variable and composing this in the function call itself.

Comment: Even better burn the question for typo.

Comment: @PierreLebon In this case it's not a typo, it's a misunderstanding on how to go from string catenation to parameters. It's an easy mistake to make and not obvious to beginners. Unless there's a duplicate it might help others as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. You can do the same without using concatenation operator (.)

Use double quotes with curly bracket and put variable inside it.

```
$q1 = "%{$q}%";
```

OR directly write

```
$q1 = "%{$_GET['q']}%";
```